# Sacar elementos de un texto con Java

Tags: java, android, text

Se asume que se tiene una aplicación **Android** que utiliza `Arcore` que mide cajas. Luego, se tiene un archivo `.txt` con el siguiente contenido:

```
BF2D@Hj04127885@rREF Z1@iEST@p@l468@n192@e35,490@d8@g@s32@v@Gl80@w-90@l80@w-90@l120@w-90@l80@w-90@l120@w-90@l80@w0@Pw1@
```

Me gustaría extraer los valores que están después de la letra `l`. En este caso, serían `468`, `80`, `80`, `120`, `80`, `120`, `80`, pero con **Java** para que el programa informe si las medidas de la cajas coinciden con las que estoy midiendo.

Comment: Añade el código que llevas para ayudarte mejor, se me ocurre por ahora tratar la cadena como un 'String' y luego con el método 'charAt()' ir verificando letra por letra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los números que buscas siempre tienen delante una "l" y detrás una "@", con lo que trataría de hacer "grupos" de elementos que voy a imprimir, que empezarían en la posición de la "l" y terminarían en la "@" posterior.

Creo el boolean "grupoCerrado, para abrir y cerrar los grupos que quiero imprimir (Así a bote pronto y sin calentarme mucho la cabeza, es lo más visual que se me ocurre).

Cuando encontramos una "l", abrimos el grupo y asignamos al inicio de la cadena, el valor de la posición "i".

Cuando encontramos la @ siguiente, asignamos al final de la cadena la nueva posición de "i".

Ahora que hemos obtenido el "grupo" de carácteres a imprimir, asignamos a la variable imprimir, el valor true, para imprimir las posiciones.

Hacemos un substring con los valores de las posiciones de inicio y fin obtenidas, lo que devolverá los números que se encuentran entre la "l" y la "@".
Seguro que se puede hacer más elegante, pero creo que hace lo que necesitas.

```
String cadena = "BF2D@Hj04127885@rREFZ1@iEST@p@l468@n192@e35,490@d8@g@s32@v@Gl80@w-90@l80@w-90@l120@w-90@l80@w-90@l120@w-90@l80@w0@Pw1@";
int inicio = 0, fin = 0;
boolean grupoCerrado = true;
boolean imprimir;

for (int i = 0; i < cadena.length(); i++) {
    imprimir=false;
    if (cadena.charAt(i) == 'l') {
        grupoCerrado = false;
        inicio = i + 1;
        //System.out.println("inicio: " + inicio + "\t");
    }
    if (cadena.charAt(i) == '@' && !grupoCerrado) {
        fin = i;
        //System.out.println("fin: " + fin + "\t");
        grupoCerrado = true;
        imprimir=true;
    }
    if (imprimir) {
        String extraccion = cadena.substring(inicio, fin);
        System.out.println(extraccion);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mi solución a base de la clase `String`espero te sirva.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String cadena = "BF2D@Hj04127885@rREF Z1@iEST@p@l468@n192@e35,490@d8@g@s32@v@Gl80@w-90@l80@w-90@l120@w-90@l80@w-90@l120@w-90@l80@w0@Pw1@";
    String[] cade = cadena.split("@");//Creamos un array de String de cada grupo de elementos antes de la @ a su vez despreciandola


    String cadeFin = "";//creamos una variable para construir un String mas legible
    for (int i = 0; i < cade.length; i++) {//recorremos el array
        for (int j = 0; j < cade[i].length(); j++) {//recorremos el grupo de caracteres que componen cada posición del array
            if (cade[i].charAt(j) == 'l') {//comparamos hasta que encontremos el caracter buscado 'l'
                for (int k = j + 1; k < cade[i].length(); k++) {//iniciamos desde la siguiente posición al caracter 'l'
                    cadeFin += cade[i].charAt(k);//asignamos todos los caracteres siguientes al 'l'
                }
                cadeFin += "-";//agregamos un diferenciador al final del numero extraído para hacer mas simple la descomposición

            }
        }

    }
    String[] fina = cadeFin.split("-");//descomponemos los números en un array
    for (String a : fina) {//se imprimen los valores (opcional)
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Salida.
**468
80
80
120
80
120
80**

Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias, En Android Studio cree un TextView donde quiero imprimir dicho resultado para que se visualice en la pantalla. Debo modificar la parte del System.out.println(a); y agregar el id del TextView verdad? Usted sabe como imprimir este numero en u textView?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5G6H_zJoTI